# SQL para avisar uma deteminada data 2 dias antes da mesma no SQLite

Tags: sqlite3

Prezados Programadores sou iniciante e gostaria de saber como faço para uma sql me avisar de uma determinada data no banco, por exemplo: 28/06/2017 quero que quando chegar dois dias antes me dê um retorno no neste caso dia 26/06/2017.

Alguém pode me ajudar o Banco é o SQLite!!

Answer (score 0):

Que tal:

```
sqlite> SELECT date( 'now', '+2 day') >= date('2017-06-24');
1
```

**Explicação:**

Se a data de hoje `2017-06-22` estiver a `+2 dias` da data do registro testado (no caso: `2017-06-24`), a expressão retornará `verdadeiro`.

Comment: Lacobus muito obrigado, sua resposta foi muito útil e ajudou muito, valeu!!!